# xml data to database using php..?? amazon xml data for product

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

I want to store amazon product in database but not geting all fields.

Does anyone have a solution ??

```
<Item>
<ASIN>B00S2SBM7W</ASIN>
<DetailPageURL>
http://www.amazon.in/A-V-Fashion-Anarkali-Dress-Materials-1621_Pink/dp/B00S2SBM7W%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6GLUVOUQSX4C2AA%26tag%3Dgettdeals-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00S2SBM7W
</DetailPageURL>
<SmallImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL75_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">50</Width>
</SmallImage>
<MediumImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL160_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">107</Width>
</MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">333</Width>
</LargeImage>
<ImageSets>
<ImageSet Category="primary">
<SwatchImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL30_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">20</Width>
</SwatchImage>
<SmallImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL75_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">50</Width>
</SmallImage>
<ThumbnailImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL75_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">50</Width>
</ThumbnailImage>
<TinyImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL110_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">110</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">73</Width>
</TinyImage>
<MediumImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL._SL160_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">107</Width>
</MediumImage>
<LargeImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/413PXhpJ-RL.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">333</Width>
</LargeImage>
</ImageSet>
</ImageSets>
<ItemAttributes>
<Binding>Apparel</Binding>
<Brand>Khantil</Brand>
<ClothingSize>Free Size</ClothingSize>
<Color>Pink</Color>
<Department>Women</Department>
<ItemDimensions>
<Height Units="hundredths-inches">224</Height>
<Length Units="hundredths-inches">1673</Length>
<Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">273</Weight>
<Width Units="hundredths-inches">1213</Width>
</ItemDimensions>
<LegalDisclaimer>
Material :Net and brasso,anarkalis and layers are stitched , rest all unstitched. BUY authentic dress from Alvineshop only Churidaar fabric- Santoon Alterable upto chest size 42 Finished Duppata- Nazneen
</LegalDisclaimer>
<MPN>Anarkali1621</MPN>
<PackageDimensions>
<Height Units="hundredths-inches">79</Height>
<Length Units="hundredths-inches">630</Length>
<Width Units="hundredths-inches">472</Width>
</PackageDimensions>
<PartNumber>Anarkali1621</PartNumber>
<ProductGroup>Apparel</ProductGroup>
<ProductTypeName>ETHNIC_WEAR</ProductTypeName>
<Size>Free Size</Size>
<Title>A.V.Fashion Anarkali Dress Materials (1621_Pink)</Title>
</ItemAttributes>
<OfferSummary>
<LowestNewPrice>
<Amount>83400</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>INR 834.00</FormattedPrice>
</LowestNewPrice>
<TotalNew>4</TotalNew>
<TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
<TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
<TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
</OfferSummary>
<Offers>
<TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers>
<TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
<MoreOffersUrl>
http://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00S2SBM7W%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6GLUVOUQSX4C2AA%26tag%3Dgettdeals-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00S2SBM7W
</MoreOffersUrl>
<Offer>
<OfferAttributes>
<Condition>New</Condition>
</OfferAttributes>
<OfferListing>
<OfferListingId>
MWBjT8ABB1ykyYoo6j65kJaRuWc8c4ErBhWT5kzwtspX87jXDB40a%2BP3Ovy%2Bg7KULdYIbWf2bwOtwfsIlRJbEJElnaazfaej8i3kE7Mz4sp%2Fj4jysBtR%2FKvnPfIbr6TgCe8Qe8atP%2B75i9Fb8QZzEwebD97evOvv
</OfferListingId>
<Price>
<Amount>83400</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>INR 834.00</FormattedPrice>
</Price>
<Availability>Usually dispatched within 1-2 business days</Availability>
<AvailabilityAttributes>
<AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>
<MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours>
<MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours>
</AvailabilityAttributes>
<IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
</OfferListing>
</Offer>
</Offers>
</Item>
```

`$items->ItemAttributes->Title`  it's ok 
but `$items->ItemAttributes->LegalDisclaimer` is result null

Comment: Nobody will send solutions to your email...

Comment: How did you get the attached output? Post some part of your code...

Comment: The purpose of posting questions at StackOverflow is to get answers on the site so that other people with similar problems don't have to ask the exact same question

Comment: Paste your code here. And tell us which lib you used for parsing XML. Did you used DOMDocument()? If so then use simplexml_load_file()

Comment: already use thi simplexml_load_file() 

foreach($pxml->Items->Item as $items )
{
// print_r($items);" <br>";
 
 var_dump($items);" <br>";
}

but not all fields are display.. only 4-5 fields are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be type casting will solve your problem.

$xml = simplexml_load_file(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../css/xml.xml');

$a=(array)$xml->ItemAttributes->LegalDisclaimer;

var_dump($a);

Output:-

Material :Net and brasso,anarkalis and layers are stitched , rest all unstitched. BUY authentic dress from Alvineshop only Churidaar fabric- Santoon Alterable upto chest size 42 Finished Duppata- Nazneen

Comment: : Undefined offset: 0 

this error occurs.. m trying to fatch data from amazon web service..

Comment: i want data from 
http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html

services

Comment: var_dump($a) result

array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: want to know what is output of $items->ItemAttributes->Title?Send me complete xml response of service.

Comment: $items->ItemAttributes->Title is ok
foreach($pxml->Items->Item as $items )
{echo $items->ItemAttributes->Title . ",<br> "; 
$pxml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Manufacturer
hear manufacture is empty result and Title is ok

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

result is ok  but 

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
this time result is not ok

Comment: make sure you are getting desired wsdl from Amazon Web Service. check  Xml response